# is it possible to render a string with \n with well formatted

Tags: html, reactjs, special-characters

When I using react to write a web page, I have a string like this:

````
"\n\nAs an AI language model, I can write the code for the bubble sort algorithm in Python:\n\n```\ndef bubble_sort(arr):\n n = len(arr)\n for i in range(n):\n for j in range(0, n-i-1):\n if arr[j] > arr[j+1] :\n arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j]\n\n```\n\nTo use the above function for sorting, pass an unsorted list, as an argument:\n\n```\nmy_list = [5, 2, 9, 1, 5, 6, 3]\nbubble_sort(my_list)\nprint(my_list) # Output will be: [1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 9]\n```\n\nThis is how the bubble sort works:\n\n- It compares the adjacent elements in an array and swaps them if the first element is greater than the second element.\n- The entire array is traversed one pass at a time.\n- After each pass, the largest element gets sorted to the end of the array, and the next pass ignores the last element since it is already sorted.\n- This process continues until the entire array is sorted."
````

is it possible to render it with a well formatted UI page? I have tried [dangous html](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html) to render, seems just works with html, not with the format in my case. I have tried like this:

```
const renderChat = () => {
        const tagList: JSX.Element[] = [];
        myMap.forEach((value, key) => {
            tagList.push(
                <div key={uuid()} className="chat-message">
                    <div key={uuid()} className="message-time">{key}</div>
                    <div key={uuid()} className="message-text">
                        <pre>{value}</pre>
                    </div>
                </div>);
        });
        return tagList;
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to format the text, just wrap the text that you have within a `<pre>` element and add curly braces. The curly braces will allow you to treat the text as a JavaScript string, so we can use the escape sequences ('\n', '\r', '\v', etc) defined.

```
<pre style={{ "text-align": "left" }}>
  {"your text\n another line"}
</pre>
```

React will escape any values in JSX, so even if you have dangerous html within the string, it is just going to be displayed as text. For example, `<img src=xss onerror=\"alert('you have been hacked')` would just be shown as text.

The `renderChat` function component has to have the first letter capitalized. Capitalized types indicate that the JSX tag is referring to a React component ([docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#specifying-the-react-element-type)). And instead of returning a `JSX.Element[] = [];` which is not a valid JSX element, you could just map over `myMap` and return it.

```
const RenderChat = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {myMap.map((value, key) => (
        <div key={uuid()} className="chat-message">
          <div key={uuid()} className="message-time">
            {key}
          </div>
          <div key={uuid()} className="message-text">
            <pre>{value}</pre>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `white-space: pre-wrap` CSS property on the text rendering component to render the `\n` as new lines in this case.

````js
let lineBreakString = "\n\nAs an AI language model, I can write the code for the bubble sort algorithm in Python:\n\n```\ndef bubble_sort(arr):\n n = len(arr)\n for i in range(n):\n for j in range(0, n-i-1):\n if arr[j] > arr[j+1] :\n arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j]\n\n```\n\nTo use the above function for sorting, pass an unsorted list, as an argument:\n\n```\nmy_list = [5, 2, 9, 1, 5, 6, 3]\nbubble_sort(my_list)\nprint(my_list) # Output will be: [1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 9]\n```\n\nThis is how the bubble sort works:\n\n- It compares the adjacent elements in an array and swaps them if the first element is greater than the second element.\n- The entire array is traversed one pass at a time.\n- After each pass, the largest element gets sorted to the end of the array, and the next pass ignores the last element since it is already sorted.\n- This process continues until the entire array is sorted.";

let textDiv = document.querySelector('#text-div');
textDiv.innerHTML = lineBreakString;
````

```css
#text-div {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="text-div"></div>
```